# date not work for set time

Tags: date, xubuntu

i use this command:

```
$ sudo date
Sat Dec 10 23:13:11 IRST 2016
$ sudo date -s '2009-02-13 11:31:30'
Fri Feb 13 11:31:30 IRST 2009
$ sudo date
Sat Dec 10 23:13:18 IRST 2016
```

but my date and time not change, my Proccess:

```
$ ps -e
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:02 systemd
    2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
    3 ?        00:00:00 ksoftirqd/0
    5 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:0H
    7 ?        00:00:06 rcu_sched
    8 ?        00:00:00 rcu_bh
    9 ?        00:00:00 migration/0
   10 ?        00:00:00 watchdog/0
   11 ?        00:00:00 kdevtmpfs
   12 ?        00:00:00 netns
   13 ?        00:00:00 perf
   14 ?        00:00:00 khungtaskd
   15 ?        00:00:00 writeback
   16 ?        00:00:00 ksmd
   17 ?        00:00:04 khugepaged
   18 ?        00:00:00 crypto
   19 ?        00:00:00 kintegrityd
   20 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   21 ?        00:00:00 kblockd
   22 ?        00:00:00 ata_sff
   23 ?        00:00:00 md
   24 ?        00:00:00 devfreq_wq
   27 ?        00:00:02 kswapd0
   28 ?        00:00:00 vmstat
   29 ?        00:00:00 fsnotify_mark
   30 ?        00:00:00 ecryptfs-kthrea
   46 ?        00:00:00 kthrotld
   47 ?        00:00:00 acpi_thermal_pm
   48 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   49 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   50 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   51 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   52 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   53 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   54 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   55 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   56 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   57 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   58 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   59 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   60 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   61 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   62 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   63 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   64 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   65 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   66 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   67 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   68 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   69 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   70 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   71 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   77 ?        00:00:00 ipv6_addrconf
   91 ?        00:00:00 deferwq
   92 ?        00:00:00 charger_manager
  129 ?        00:00:00 bioset
  130 ?        00:00:00 bioset
  131 ?        00:00:00 bioset
  132 ?        00:00:00 bioset
  133 ?        00:00:00 bioset
  134 ?        00:00:00 bioset
  135 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_0
  136 ?        00:00:00 bioset
  137 ?        00:00:00 scsi_tmf_0
  138 ?        00:00:00 bioset
  139 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_1
  140 ?        00:00:00 scsi_tmf_1
  141 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_2
  142 ?        00:00:00 scsi_tmf_2
  143 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_3
  144 ?        00:00:00 scsi_tmf_3
  146 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_4
  148 ?        00:00:00 scsi_tmf_4
  151 ?        00:00:00 scsi_eh_5
  152 ?        00:00:00 scsi_tmf_5
  156 ?        00:00:00 kfd_process_wq
  157 ?        00:00:00 ttm_swap
  158 ?        00:00:00 radeon-crtc
  159 ?        00:00:00 radeon-crtc
  160 ?        00:00:00 bioset
  182 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:1H
  184 ?        00:00:00 jbd2/sda1-8
  185 ?        00:00:00 ext4-rsv-conver
  220 ?        00:00:00 systemd-journal
  222 ?        00:00:00 kauditd
  272 ?        00:00:00 systemd-udevd
  429 ?        00:00:00 systemd-timesyn
  435 ?        00:00:00 edac-poller
  523 ?        00:00:00 kvm-irqfd-clean
  601 ?        00:00:00 whoopsie
  607 ?        00:00:00 rsyslogd
  610 ?        00:00:00 acpid
  617 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon
  623 ?        00:00:00 ModemManager
  636 ?        00:00:01 dbus-daemon
  673 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon
  685 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager
  690 ?        00:00:00 snapd
  696 ?        00:00:00 systemd-logind
  699 ?        00:00:00 cups-browsed
  702 ?        00:00:00 cron
  703 ?        00:00:00 accounts-daemon
  789 ?        00:00:00 polkitd
  833 ?        00:00:00 lightdm
  850 tty7     00:05:44 Xorg
  862 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm7.0
  865 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm7.0
  866 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm7.0
  868 ?        00:00:00 dhclient
  881 ?        00:00:00 dnsmasq
 1121 tty1     00:00:00 agetty
 1145 ?        00:00:00 iprt-VBoxWQueue
 1181 ?        00:00:00 rtkit-daemon
 1212 ?        00:00:00 lightdm
 1267 ?        00:00:00 systemd
 1270 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
 1275 ?        00:00:00 gnome-keyring-d
 1277 ?        00:00:00 upstart
 1341 ?        00:00:00 upstart-udev-br
 1348 ?        00:00:01 dbus-daemon
 1417 ?        00:00:00 gpg-agent
 1420 ?        00:00:00 upstart-dbus-br
 1422 ?        00:00:00 upstart-dbus-br
 1425 ?        00:00:00 upstart-file-br
 1435 ?        00:00:00 sh
 1446 ?        00:00:00 xfce4-session
 1453 ?        00:00:00 xfconfd
 1459 ?        00:00:37 xfwm4
 1463 ?        00:00:25 xfce4-panel
 1467 ?        00:00:11 xfdesktop
 1468 ?        00:00:01 blueman-applet
 1471 ?        00:00:00 update-notifier
 1476 ?        00:00:02 pulseaudio
 1478 ?        00:00:00 polkit-gnome-au
 1479 ?        00:00:00 light-locker
 1480 ?        00:00:00 nm-applet
 1485 ?        00:00:00 xfce4-volumed
 1486 ?        00:00:00 applet.py
 1492 ?        00:00:00 at-spi-bus-laun
 1496 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd
 1501 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd-fuse
 1505 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
 1513 ?        00:00:01 at-spi2-registr
 1517 ?        00:00:00 xfce4-power-man
 1518 ?        00:00:01 xfsettingsd
 1521 ?        00:00:00 upowerd
 1577 ?        00:00:00 dconf-service
 1598 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-udisks2-vo
 1602 ?        00:00:00 udisksd
 1604 ?        00:00:00 panel-14-places
 1609 ?        00:00:00 panel-16-screen
 1614 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-goa-volume
 1620 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-mtp-volume
 1621 ?        00:00:03 xfce4-xkb-plugi
 1626 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-afc-volume
 1627 ?        00:00:00 panel-4-systray
 1632 ?        00:00:04 panel-10-cpugra
 1634 ?        00:00:00 gvfs-gphoto2-vo
 1635 ?        00:00:02 panel-19-weathe
 1661 ?        00:00:00 upstart
 1663 ?        00:00:00 indicator-messa
 1664 ?        00:00:00 indicator-sound
 1672 ?        00:00:00 indicator-appli
 1727 ?        00:00:00 obexd
 1807 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
 1839 ?        00:00:01 panel-6-indicat
 1844 ?        00:00:00 upstart
 2104 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd-metadata
 2108 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd-trash
 2198 ?        00:00:00 gconfd-2
 2240 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u4:0
 2349 ?        00:00:11 stardict
 2351 ?        00:00:00 bonobo-activati
 2563 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
 2885 ?        00:00:14 xfce4-terminal
 2889 ?        00:00:00 gnome-pty-helpe
 2890 pts/0    00:00:01 bash
 2905 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
 2941 ?        00:00:00 gconfd-2
 2968 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
 3048 ?        00:00:00 gvfsd
 3246 ?        00:00:06 Thunar
 3438 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
 3715 pts/6    00:00:00 bash
 3730 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
 3800 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
 3841 ?        00:05:01 firefox
 3931 ?        00:00:01 kworker/0:1
 4035 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
 4048 ?        00:00:00 system-tools-ba
 4052 ?        00:00:00 SystemToolsBack
 4170 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
 4253 ?        00:00:00 kworker/u4:1
 4358 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:0
 4381 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
 4396 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
 4435 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:2
 4439 pts/6    00:00:00 ps
```

i have `xUbuntu 16.04.1 LTS`:

```
$ uname -a
Linux wundoz 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

how to fix this?

Comment: i no want change `hwclock` time and date

Comment: @JimFell the answers there recommend doing exactly what the OP has already done. I don't see how this is a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that it is the systemd-timesyncd service (pid 429) that updates your clock to current time.
This process appears in your list as systemd-timesyn , but if you `ps 429` the full name will appear.

By running `timedatectl status` you should get info about date and time.
At the end you will see :

```
Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: no
```

`systemd-timesyncd` refers to "Network time" above.

It seems that ntp services are not present in your process list, so by stopping systemd-timesyncd service you should be able to change time/date.

In my machine Network time is active, while NTP is not; I suppose you will have the same in your machine, since i can not see any ntp related service in your process list (ntpdate or ntpd)

You can get more info about `systemd-timesyncd.service` by running:

```
#systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service
```

The output of above command will give you info about the auto updating servers, like this :

```
Status: "Synchronized to time server 196.10.52.57:123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org)."
```

In Ubuntu it is said that ntpdate (ntpd) service could be running by default, at least at boot time. You can make a double check for possibly running ntp services with `# top -p $(echo $(pgrep "nt") |sed 's/ /,/g')` and look if something related to ntp is running (i dont think so)

Tip: If you check `timedatectl --help` you will see options to set time by `timedatectl` tool, which might work better by `date -s` (not tested)

CoreOs has a [nice article](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/configuring-date-and-timezone.html) about date/time services.

Comment: @Babyy : Did this worked?

Comment: i use this command for temporary stop this service `sudo systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd`, thank you